# Option box table only searchs with number on SQL (MS-Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have made a table with placements.
It says

1. New York
2. Washington

I use the table in another table and form where the user can select a city.
But when I try to query the selected value with SQL, I can only search on the ID.
Like

```
SELECT Articles.Name
FROM Articles
WHERE (((Articles.Placement.Value)=1);
```

I would like to search by name instead. How is that done? I simply can't find any info on that anywhere.

```
 SELECT Articles.Name
    FROM Articles
    WHERE (Articles.Placement="New York");
```

Comment: Is Articles.Placement a lookup field in table? If you have a combobox for selecting placement, users select "New York" from combobox but code uses the ID value. Searching on indexed keys is more efficient.

Comment: Hi there. Yes, its is actually two lookup tables. One as checkboxes and one as drop down list.
Ok I will try to find some info on RecordSource.

Comment: Ooops, I edited my comment after you read it. Read again.

Comment: Ok, I will try indexed keys.

Comment: Aren't your PK/FK fields already indexed? Posted SQL does not show dynamic parameter - why not? Does your actual SQL have dynamic parameter?

Comment: I'm sorry I simply dont know that..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233990/discussion-between-june7-and-pbl-dk).

Comment: I am getting something to work with Gordons reply. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM Articles as a INNER JOIN
     Placements as p
     ON a.Placement_ID = p.Placement_Id
WHERE p.Placement = "New York";
```

Comment: Thanks I got it to work with join. But the ID was'nt necessary, it was in the value itself apparently. Now I have something to work on. Cheers.

SELECT a.Name
FROM Articles as a INNER JOIN
     Placements as p
     ON a.Placement = p.Placement_Id
WHERE p.Placement = "New York";